# $8$ billion people in the world, increase each year by $2\%$, how many people will be in $9$ months?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I have the following ODE problem :

$8$ billion people in the world, increase each year by $2\%$, how many people will be in $9$ months?

**What I did :**

The change each year is : $$x'(t)=0.02(x(t))$$

Therefore $$x(t)=Ce^{0.02t}$$

In $t_0$ we know that $x(t_0)=8$, therefore $C=8*e^{-0.02t_0}$

So I got that $$x(t)=8*e^{(0.02(t-t_0))}$$

The number of people in $9$ months are $t-t_0=3/4$

Therefore I got : $$x(t)=8*e^{0.02(0.75)}=8.1209$$

In the text book the right answer is $8.1197$

I don't understand what's wrong with my solution.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This is wrong: $x′(t)=\color{red}{0.02}(x(t)).$ The problem statement says an integrated increase in one year to be $0.02$ relative to the starting value, not the current rate of growth.

Comment: Thank you, Just to make sure I understand correctly the equation : $x'(t) = 0.02(x(t))$ means that the growth rate $(x'(t))$ of the population in time $t$ is defined by amount of people multiply by $0.02$ $(x(t)*0.02)$ its not correct since the change of the rate growth depends on the  starting value $(t_0=0)$ hence present time.

Comment: Not exactly. The coefficient describes an instant change rate, as a proportion to the current value at the moment. But since the value changes continuously, the absolute speed of change in next moments will change and the change accumulated across a period of time will differ from the instant rate. <br> The ODE $dx/dt = k\,x(t)$ has a solution $x=A\exp(kt)$, which results in an annual growth ratio $x(t+1)/x(t) = \exp(k(t+1))/\exp(kt) = \exp(k)$. For your specific data you need it to be $+2\%$, so $\exp(k) = 1.02$ hence $k=\ln 1.02 \approx 0.0198$, not $\color{red}{0.02}$.

Comment: Then, the population (in millions) after 9 months, i.e. 3/4 of a year: $x(t+3/4) = A\exp(kt)\exp(3/4\,k) = 8(\exp k)^{3/4} = 8\cdot 1.02^{3/4} \approx 8\cdot 1.014963$ (can you see how the actual value of $k$ disappeared?), which is approx 8.1197 million people.

Comment: Whoops, I confused millions and billions in the comment above. :) Hopefully, the numeric part is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to assume the exponential form to begin with. In fact, if this is an exercise on ordinary differential equations, then you shouldn't in fact assume the form.

Instead, recognise the basic behaviour - this is a continuous growth model where the rate of increase of population $\frac {dP}{dt}$ is proportional to the present population $P$. Let the constant of proportionality be an unknown $k$ (which is to be determined).

So you start with $\frac{dP}{dt} = kP$, solve it to get $\ln P = kt + C$, where $C$ is another constant (of indefinite integration), giving $P = Ce^{kt}$.

Now, you know that when $t=0$ (at the start), the population is $P_0$, the initial population. So $P_0 = C$, and the solution can be written $P = P_0e^{kt}$.

You're also told that when $t=1$, $P = 1.02P_0$ (that's how you use the $2 \%$ increase given in the question).

So $1.02P_0 = P_0e^{k}$, giving $k = \ln{1.02}$.

Your final equation is therefore $P = P_0e^{t\ln{1.02}} = P_01.02^t = (8 \times 10^9)1.02^t$, into which you can substitute $t=0.75$ to get the correct required value.

So, pro tip: don't start out assuming the constants in your ODE, get a general form first then work out the constants using what's given.

Answer (score 2):

The function that you're after is an exponential one; to be more precise, it is of the type $f(t)=8e^{kt}$. What is the value of $k$? It musto be such that $f(1)=8\times1.02$, which means that $k=\log(1.02)$. So, $f(t)=8e^{\log(1.02)t}$ and $f(1)$ is indeed about $8.1197$.

Comment: But the change each year is defined by $x′(t)=0.02(x(t))$ therefore $k=0.02$ in $t_0=0$ while $t_0$ is present time we get that $f(0)=8$

Comment: No, it is *not* defined like that. It is defined so that $x(t+1)=1.02\times x(t)$. And your function does *not* fulfill this condition.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

> The change each year is :
>   $$x′(t)=0.02(x(t))$$

Plug in you your numbers:

$$x(t)=8∗e^{0.02(t−t_0)}$$

At $t=1+t_0$ year we get

$$x(1)=8∗e^{0.02}$$

or

$$x(1) = 8161610720.21$$

The question clearly stated that over 1 year, the people would increase by 2%.  2% of 8 billion is 160 million, not 161.6 million.

The core of the problem is:

$$x′(t)=0.02(x(t))$$

does not correspond to an annual growth rate of 2%.  It corresponds to an annual growth rate a bit over 2%.

You want

$$x′(t)=\ln(1.02)(x(t))$$

for an annual growth rate of 2%.

That gives you an equation of

$$x(t)=8∗e^{\ln(1.02)(t−t_0)}$$

and $x(1) = 8 * e^{\ln(1.02)} = 8 *1.02 $ as the problem requires.

Your answer is close because $\ln(1+x)$ ~ $x$ for small $x$.

$x'(t) = 0.02x(t)$ means that the derivative at a point t is 0.02 times the value at point t.  That isn't quite the right value to produce a growth factor of 1.02 from $t=0$ to $t=1$, because that growth compounds.

Comment: If you prefix the logarithmic function name with a backslash, LaTeX/MathJax will recognize it as a symbol, and render it in an upright font with appropriate spacing: `m\ln x` → $m\ln x$, instead of a formless mass of italics: `m ln x` → $m ln x$.